# how to update view in Group in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a graph look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umXqs.png). I want to update view when I change slider. However, all elements will stacked together look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek4Y0.png) when I change slider. So what can I do to get a new view.

my app's structrue:

Circle and QuadCurve -> Group -> ScrollPane -> BorderPane -> Scene -> Stage

Comment: I suppose you forgot to remove children of the group when you move the slider. More code can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This app demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. Comments are in the code.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication6 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Group groupMain;

    @FXML
    private Circle cirMain, cirCenter, cirRadius1, cirRadius2, cirRadius3;

    @FXML
    private Slider sliderMain;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO



    }    

    @FXML void handleButton(ActionEvent event)
    {
        double radius = cirMain.getRadius();//Get transparent mainCircle radius   

        System.out.println(radius + " : " +  cirMain.getLayoutX() + " : " +  cirMain.getLayoutY());

        cirRadius1.setRadius(20);
        cirRadius1.setLayoutX(radius * Math.cos(50) + cirMain.getLayoutX());//set cirRadius1 to x location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius1.setLayoutY(radius * Math.sin(50) + cirMain.getLayoutY());//set cirRadius1 to y location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius1.setFill(Color.RED);

        cirRadius2.setRadius(10);
        cirRadius2.setLayoutX(radius * Math.cos(175) + cirMain.getLayoutX());//set cirRadius2 to x location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius2.setLayoutY(radius * Math.sin(175) + cirMain.getLayoutY());//set cirRadius2 to y location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius2.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        cirRadius3.setRadius(15);
        cirRadius3.setLayoutX(radius * Math.cos(300) + cirMain.getLayoutX());//set cirRadius3 to x location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius3.setLayoutY(radius * Math.sin(300) + cirMain.getLayoutY());//set cirRadius3 to y location on circumference of cirMain
        cirRadius3.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        sliderMain.setValue(radius);//set slider value to current cirMain radius


        //This listener moves the circle inward or outward depending on the slider. It also changes the radius of cirMain's radius
        sliderMain.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)->{
            cirMain.setRadius(newVal.doubleValue());
            cirRadius1.setLayoutX(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.cos(50) + cirMain.getLayoutX());
            cirRadius1.setLayoutY(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.sin(50) + cirMain.getLayoutY());

            cirRadius2.setLayoutX(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.cos(175) + cirMain.getLayoutX());
            cirRadius2.setLayoutY(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.sin(175) + cirMain.getLayoutY());

            cirRadius3.setLayoutX(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.cos(300) + cirMain.getLayoutX());
            cirRadius3.setLayoutY(newVal.doubleValue() * Math.sin(300) + cirMain.getLayoutY());
        });

    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="518.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication6.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Circle fx:id="cirMain" fill="#ededed00" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="200.0" radius="175.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle fx:id="cirCenter" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="200.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle fx:id="cirRadius1" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="156.0" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle fx:id="cirRadius2" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="412.0" layoutY="166.0" radius="35.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Circle fx:id="cirRadius3" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="290.0" radius="27.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      <Button layoutX="288.0" layoutY="479.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" text="Button" />
      <Slider fx:id="sliderMain" blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="418.0" max="200.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="551.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: thanks, I will try to improve my app referring to your example.